# How to get img src url inside a href html tags

Tags: php

how to get the img url from a href html tags?

Example url source:

`<img src="/upload/image.jpg" />`

and get the url example
http://example.com/upload/image.jpg

Comment: Easily done by js, just give a try.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked and answered many times, Please Google before asking anything. You can easily get the Value set in 'href' html tag by below jQuery:

```
var href = $('#ImageID').attr('href');
```